# In Eloquent, is there a way to use sql functions in relationship query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am working in Eloquent with Laravel, and I have a table named `invoices.`

Each invoice has a prefix that identifies the `dealer id`.

For example,
`01-1234` is an invoice from `dealer 01`. `02-5678` is an invoice from `dealer 02`.

Further complicating things is that the dealer's id is not `01` or `02`, but `DEALER01` or `DEALER02`.

I would like to know if it's possible to get a query like this to work, so that the invoice object has an associated dealer object, without having to write a lot of repetitive code to loop through the invoices and manually link them.

```php
public function dealer() {
    return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class, 'dealerId', 'concat(\'DEALER\', substr(Invoice.invoice, 1, 2))')
}
```

Here are a few fields from the table structure of invoice:

| invoice | cust | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-1234 | 1 | 2021-06-05 |
| 02-1235 | 2 | 2021-06-06 |

And here are a few fields from the structure of dealer:

| dealerId | county | default_sales_acct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DEALER01 | Some county | 1234 |
| DEALER02 | Some other county | 5678 |

The only fields needed to link the two tables in this case are dealerId and the first two characters of invoice.

Comment: show table structure of invoice

Comment: @JohnLobo I added a bit to give an idea about the table structure.

Comment: @Tmorgan.thanks for adding.:)

Comment: Have you decided this structure or is it already an existing database ?

Comment: @TMorgan.better create separate column in database otherwise you might need to override hasmany relationship

Comment: @matiaslauriti this is an existing database, so we would have to be careful about making changes, particularly in how relationships are stored.

Comment: @JohnLobo I considered creating a view that encapsulated this functionality, but that would be read-only. Adding a field, with a trigger that automatically updated that when a record was inserted my work.

Comment: @TMorgan.thats the better solution if you has one relationship